# Delete X many words in direction, Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to specify how many **words** to delete in any given direction?  I know that there's a way to specify how many **letters** to delete, but what about words?

Like I'm hoping for something along these lines:

```
2X <DIRECTION>
```

So I can take something like this:

```
inoremap <F14>    <ESC>:call Smode('hlon')<CR>|
```

and turn it into this:

```
inoremap <F14>    <ESC><CR>|
```

Comment: While you are at it, take 5 minutes to read and do this tutorial : http://www.glump.net/files/2012/08/vi-vim-cheat-sheet-and-tutorial.pdf, it contains solution for your problem as much as others .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Delete 2 words in **forward** direction:

```
d2w
```

Delete 2 words in **backward** direction:

```
d2b
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop.

Before you do anything else, run `vimtutor`. It contains all the low-level information you need to start using Vim. Including the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find exactly what I wanted but this works just as well:

```
v2ex
```

Enter *visual mode*, move forward to the end of the *second* **lowercase** (use `E` 
for uppercase) word, and *delete* selected text.

Comment: Note: `d` and `x` in visual mode both do the same thing, and on most keyboard layouts `d` is easier to reach.